# Why is ($z_1$-$z_2$i) + ($w_1$-$w_2$i) = ($z_1$+$w_1$) - ($z_2$+$w_2$)i

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $z = z_1 + z_2i$ and $w = w_1 + w_2i$ be complex numbers. The question asks to show that $\overline{z+w}$ = $\overline{z} + \overline{w}$ for all z and w. The answer proves it by saying that ($z_1$-$z_2$i) + ($w_1$-$w_2$i) = ($z_1$+$w_1$) - ($z_2$+$w_2$)i, but I don't understand how they equal each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z=a+bi$ and let $w=c+di$, then we have:
$$\overline{z+w}=(a+c)-i(b+d)$$
While:
$$\overline{z}=a+bi \land \overline{w}=c-di$$
Combining, we have
$$\overline{z}+ \overline{w}=a-bi+c-di=(a+c)-i(b+d)$$
This shows you that the two quantities are equal, so:
$$\overline{z+w}=\overline{z}+\overline{w}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of $(a-b)+(c-d)=(a+c)-(b+d)$, which is valid in any field, including $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$. It repeatedly uses the fact that $+$ commutes and associates.